# Ftp File download From java code

Tags: java, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

i have this code to download a single file .

```
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
public class NetTest {
public static void main(String[] args){
FTPClient client = new FTPClient( );
OutputStream outStream;
    try {
```

this is the part of server and passwords .

```
   client.connect( "servername" );
    client.login("noman123", "pass");
    String remoteFile = "/a.txt";
    outStream = new FileOutputStream( "a.txt" );
```

simple fill downloading but error on this line

```
    client.retrieveFile( remoteFile, outStream );
} catch(IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println( "Error communicating with FTP server." );
} finally {
    try {
        client.disconnect( );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println( "Problem disconnecting from FTP server" );
    }
}

}
}
```

and it gives me errors like 
i hope that u can understand the issue that i m facing now

> java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
>           at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
>           at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
>           at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
>           at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
>           at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__send(FTP.java:496)
>           at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:470)
>           at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:547)
>           at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.port(FTP.java:872)
>           at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.*openDataConnection*(FTPClient.java:667)
>           at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.retrieveFile(FTPClient.java:1595)
>           at FtpDownloadDemo.main(FtpDownloadDemo.java:25)

Comment: Instead of printing a custom message, you should print the stack trace which would most likely give you useful information about what happened. (`ioe.printStackTrace()`)

Comment: i already done this but it gives me un understandable texts

Comment: that un-understandable text could be very useful. Why don't you edit your question and add the content of that text at the bottom?

Comment: You have clicked on edit below your question, added your text and saved the edit?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607026/ant-ftp-task-fails-java-net-socketexception which suggests a firewall issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

turn off the firewall.in this issue

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you can ping the server and log in manually, but assuming you're ok there, there's two additional things I would do.

1) Per the FTP Client documentation, check that you're really connected

```
// After connection attempt, you should check the reply code to verify success.
reply = client.getReplyCode();
if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply))
        { // print more complete error }
```

There's a full example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/UsetheFTPClient.htm).

2) It could be since you're trying to get the remote file "/a.txt" you're trying to get to the root directory and your ftp server isn't set up to allow you access.  Try just "a.txt" in whichever directory your ftp client is set to dump a user into.

Comment: i just done this and it says that i m connected and on the root but when i try to access some data it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on the given example code that you should call the **enterLocalPassiveMode** method of FTPClient if you are behind a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

read this article https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7077696

WORK AROUND to solve this problem start program with

> -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true